# Angular Kendo-ui scss, can't get webpack to build

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, kendo-ui-angular2

Webpack won't build after I included kendo ui default theme in an scss file.

The error message I receive is:

> ERROR in ./src/app/vendor/kendo-ui/theme.scss
>       Module build failed: TypeError: URL.startsWith is not a function

I understand that this error occurs because the URL isn't a string, however the code we're using worked fine in angular 4, it's only shifting to angular 5 that this issue occurred.

Any suggestions to get it going would be greatly appreciated

kendo is imported like so:

```
@import '~@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/all';
```

webpack code for scss looks like this

```
{
    test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        use: [
             'exports-loader?module.exports.toString()',
             {
                 loader: 'css-loader',
                 options: {
                     sourceMap: false,
                     importLoaders: 1
                 }
             },
             {
                 loader: 'postcss-loader',
                 options: {
                     ident: 'postcss',
                     plugins: postcssPlugins
                    }
             },
             {
                  loader: 'sass-loader',
                  options: {
                      sourceMap: false,
                      precision: 8,
                      includePaths: []
                  }
             }
      ]
}
```

The postcssPlugins function..

```
const postcssPlugins = function () {
// safe settings based on: https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano/issues/358#issuecomment-283696193
const importantCommentRe = /@preserve|@license|[@#]\s*source(?:Mapping)?URL|^!/i;
const minimizeOptions = {
    autoprefixer: false,
    safe: true,
    mergeLonghand: false,
    discardComments: { remove: (comment) => !importantCommentRe.test(comment) }
};
return [
    postcssUrl({
        url: (URL) => {
            // Only convert root relative URLs, which CSS-Loader won't process into require().
            if (!URL.startsWith('/') || URL.startsWith('//')) {
                return URL;
            }
            if (deployUrl.match(/:\/\//)) {
                // If deployUrl contains a scheme, ignore baseHref use deployUrl as is.
                return `${deployUrl.replace(/\/$/, '')}${URL}`;
            }
            else if (baseHref.match(/:\/\//)) {
                // If baseHref contains a scheme, include it as is.
                return baseHref.replace(/\/$/, '') +
                    `/${deployUrl}/${URL}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
            }
            else {
                // Join together base-href, deploy-url and the original URL.
                // Also dedupe multiple slashes into single ones.
                return `/${baseHref}/${deployUrl}/${URL}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
            }
        }
    }),
    autoprefixer(),
    ].concat(minimizeCss ? [cssnano(minimizeOptions)] : []);
};
```

Using

- Angular: 5.2.7
- webpack: 3.11.0
- "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.48.1",

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

Taking a look at the code you've posted I've made a couple of assumptions

1. `postcssUrl(....)` this function comes from the npm package `postcss-url`
2. you are using Angular CLI

The starting with Angular CLI 1.6.0-rc0 the npm package `postcss-url` was updated from `^5.1.2` to `7.1.2` ([commit](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/def8f6294a2a9af0468d8d0b2e1fff1774b2fcbb))

Starting with `postcss-url@6.0.0` the `url` option was changed so that the function it accepts is given different parameters, the URL used to be the first parameter but is now contained in an object.

You can view the old parameters [here](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-url/tree/5.1.2#url-function) and the current parameters [here](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-url/tree/7.1.2#url-function)

Hope this helps!

---

**ORIGINAL:**

Based on the error that you have posted it looks like the `URL` parameter in your postcssPlugins function is not a string type.

I would recommend putting a `console.log(URL)` at the top of your function just to see what it returns as the type of the input parameter may have changed between versions.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, yes as mentioned in post I understand that this error occurs because the URL isn't a string